# Extract Javascript Variables from Scraped HTML Page using PHP (Regex)

Tags: javascript, php, regex, scrape

I'm stuggling to extract Javascript variables from a scraped webpage's HTML dump.

Currently using this regex

```
    $re = '/window\.universal_variable\s*=\s*\{(.*?)\}/ms';
```

but it only shows me the first set of values. I'm basically trying to get all variables and values that are under product (i.e. id, product_id, sku, etc)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
window.universal_variable = {
page: {
category: "product" ,
searchTerm: "sony",
environment: "production",
variation: "production",
revision: "1.1"
},
user: {
otb: "",
ATG_FO_IND: "A",\t
ooops_preference: "false",
registered_today: false,
registration_date: "",
registered_in_current_session: false,\tidv_verified: true,
last_order_date: "",
start_date: "",
first_order: false,\treturning: false,
last_transaction_payment_type: "",
unicaSegment: "",
targetedPromos :"",
cva:"0",
cvb:"1", 
cvc:""
}// end of user\t
,\t
product:{
id: "KEN6C",
product_id: "prod1086433641",
sku: "KEN6C",
manufacturer: "",
category: "Televisions",
category_facet: "4740",
department: "Electricals",
subcategory: "electricals_televisions",
currency: "GBP",
unit_price: "",
unit_sale_price: "319.0",
rating: "4.3",
ratingCount: "2048"
}// end of product
}// end of window.universal_variable\t
window.sdgGA = {
environment: "production",
device: "desktop",
userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36",
currency: "GBP",
page: {
PID: "test : PRODUCT",
loggedInState: "not logged in",
category:"product",
customerStatus: "new"
},

</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to do it with a regex, which would be extremely brittle, I would suggest using a transpiler such as [this one](https://github.com/sstur/js2php). I tested it on your example code and it worked great.

Comment: Amazing. I'll give it a go

Comment: In this case, what would a good Regex be to extract everything between js tags?

Comment: I would also not recommend regex for that, since there's no knowing ahead of time how many levels of nested tags there are, plus HTML has void tags which may or may not have closing slashes, which makes it complicated. This answer is what I would probably do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1677190/5774952, but there are some regex examples in other answers on that question.